# Is there any way to get log events from crashlytics / fabric into ELK or a SaaS metrics platform like datadog?

Tags: mobile-devices, fabric, elk, datadog, crashlytics

If you use a stack like ELK or datadog for collecting server-side logs and events, how do you integrate mobile-side metrics? Is there any way to get these out of crashlytics directly, or does this log aggregation need to be implemented separately?